# S3A client and local S3 mock

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-sdk

To create end-to-end local tests of data workflow I utilize "mock S3" container (e.g [adobe/S3Mock](https://github.com/adobe/S3Mock)). Seems to work just fine. However, some parts of the system rely on S3A client. As far as I see, its format does not allow to point to particular nameserver or endpoint.

Is it possible to make S3A work in local environment?

Answer (score 3):

you talking about the ASF Hadoop S3A Connector? Nobody has tested against S3 mock AFAIK (never seen it before!), but it does work with non-AWS endpoints

set `fs.s3a.endpoint` to the URL of your S3 connection. There's some settings about switching from https to http (fs.s3a.connection.ssl.enabled = false) and moving from virtual hosts to directories (fs.s3a.path.style.access = true) which will also be needed.

[further reading](https://hortonworks.github.io/hdp-aws/s3-configure/index.html)

Like I said: nobody has done this. We developers just go against the main AWS endpoints with its problems (latency, inconsistency, error reporting, etc), precisely because its what you get in production. But for your local testing, it will simplify your life (and you can run it under jenkins without having to give it any secrets)

Comment: Thank you. These properties seem to be helpful to achieve it. I couldn't figure it out though and got stuck with vague timeout exception. It might be a matter of S3 fake server as well so I decided to work on the real S3.

Answer (score 0):

Answer by @stevel worked for me. Here is the code if someone wants to refer

```html
class S3WriterTest {

    private static S3Mock api;
    private static AmazonS3 mockS3client;

    @BeforeAll
    public static void setUp() {
        //start mock s3 service using findify
        api = new S3Mock.Builder().withPort(8001).withInMemoryBackend().build();
        api.start();

        /* AWS S3 client setup.
         *  withPathStyleAccessEnabled(true) trick is required to overcome S3 default
         *  DNS-based bucket access scheme
         *  resulting in attempts to connect to addresses like "bucketname.localhost"
         *  which requires specific DNS setup.
         */
        EndpointConfiguration endpoint = new EndpointConfiguration("http://localhost:8001", "us-west-2");
        mockS3client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder
            .standard()
            .withEndpointConfiguration(endpoint)
            .withPathStyleAccessEnabled(true)
            .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(new AnonymousAWSCredentials()))
            .build();

        mockS3client.createBucket("test-bucket");
    }

    @AfterAll
    public static void tearDown() {
        api.shutdown();
    }

    @Test
    void unitTestForHadoopCodeWritingUsingS3A {
        Configuration hadoopConfig = getTestConfiguration();
        ........
    }

    private static Configuration getTestConfiguration() {
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.set("fs.s3a.endpoint", "http://127.0.0.1:8001");
        config.set("fs.s3a.connection.ssl.enabled", "false");
        config.set("fs.s3a.path.style.access", "true");
        config.set("fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.SimpleAWSCredentialsProvider");
        config.set("fs.s3a.access.key", "foo");
        config.set("fs.s3a.secret.key", "bar");
        return config;
    }
 }
```